# Inno Setup - open link only with Internet Explorer

Tags: inno-setup

Im using these code to open a htm file but the problem is that i need that file to be open only with Internet Explorer.

How can i achieve that?
Thank you!

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
    ErrCode: integer;
begin
    if (CurStep=ssPostInstall) then
    begin
        ShellExec('open',ExpandConstant('{userdesktop}\Tutoriais\index.htm'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrCode);        
    end;

    end;
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to open the IE directly, and giving it the htm file as a start parameter?

Comment: Execute `iexplore` and as a parameter pass your HTML file.

Comment: @TLama Isn't that exactly what my comment said? ;)

Comment: @Adam, yup, I was just a little more specific... :-)

Comment: Guys, i cant find anywhere how i can execute iexplore in the code section and pass the file as parameter. Just pieces of code on how to detect IE version. Can you give me a hint?Thanks!

Comment: I was being dumb! :) 
I used the RUN section with this line of code to solve my problems:
Filename: iexplore.exe; Parameters: "{userdesktop}\Tutoriais\index.htm"; Verb: open; Flags: shellexec runasoriginaluser

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I used the RUN section with this line of code to solve this question:

```
[Run]
Filename: iexplore.exe; Parameters: "{userdesktop}\Tutoriais\index.htm"; Verb: open; Flags: shellexec runasoriginaluser
```

Thank you !